# Get-AzureStorageBlob returns null

Tags: powershell, azure-storage

I am trying to get a blob from azure:

```
$name = "myfolder/20180223_064819[1].jpg"
$blob = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $container.Name -Context $context -Blob $name -ErrorAction Stop 
$blob -eq $null # is True
```

and the file is present in storage, in the location specified above, I can see it using the azure storage explorer. However $blob is $null rather than throwing an error which is what usually happens when no file is found. I have been accessing other files fine.

If I create another file myfile/201802230648191.jpg. In this code $blob2 returns an object (which is what you'd expect)

```
$name = "myfolder/201802230648191.jpg"
$blob2 = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $container.Name -Context $context -Blob $name -ErrorAction Stop 
$blob2 -eq $null # is False
```

I have tried url escaping the name but then it throws a not found exception. I have looked at the naming rules here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Naming-and-Referencing-Containers--Blobs--and-Metadata but don't appear to be violating any.

So, my question is, why does $blob return null instead of the object?

And also, How can I get blobs with a name containing [ or ] ?

Answer (score 0):

I test your code and got the same [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAvIW.png) as you. Then I checked the `Get-AzureStorageBlob` [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/powershell/module/azure.storage/get-azurestorageblob?view=azurermps-6.12.0#optional-parameters) and I found it supports **wildcard search** even the support for `Accept wildcard characters` is **false**.

Then I further tested the code. I changed the picture name to  `Snipaste_2018-11-02_13-56-321.png` without **[]** and still use the code, It worked. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTIOb.png) is the result. So the problem is because the **[]** in the `$name` was recognized as wildcard characters.

So if you still insist your name, you could use `-Prefix` instead of `-Blob`. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u02aG.png) is my result.

If you still have questions, please let me know.

Comment: @johnstaveley if my answer could help you, could you accept my answer.Thanks.

Comment: But prefix searches for the first part of a file name e.g. -Prefix abc will match abc.jpg abc.png etc. How can I get files with a name containing [ or ] ?

Comment: Yes,you could search without suffix, however you could also search with it like my picture shows.

Comment: @johnstaveley and i tried to search files with same names but different suffix, it works.

Comment: @johnstaveley you could just search file name abc.jpg or abc.png with prefix.

Comment: You can find my $name is full name with suffix.

Comment: Ok but what if the name contains [ or ]? I am still doing a regex search when I don't want to

Answer (score 0):

I have answer this question in: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/7848#issuecomment-439307333

Generally agree with George, use `-prefix` should be work since `-prefix` not support wildcard search. Anyway, this will also get other blob start with the blob name, like `test/new11_22[1].jpgab`, to only get the matched blob, you can filter the blobs with a pipeline like:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>> Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $containerName -Context $ctx -prefix test/new11_22[1].jpg | ? {$_.Name -eq "test/new11_22[1].jpg"}


   Container Uri: https://***.blob.core.windows.net/***

Name                 BlobType  Length          ContentType                    LastModified         AccessTier SnapshotTime         IsDeleted 
----                 --------  ------          -----------                    ------------         ---------- ------------         --------- 
test/new11_22[1].jpg BlockBlob 2097152         application/octet-stream       2018-11-16 07:29:19Z                                 False
```

Actually the benavior of Get-AzureStorageBlob is aligned with other Powershell cmdlets like Get-Item:
like for file `c:\temp\new11_22[1].jpg`, following is the result.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> get-item c:\temp\new11_22[1].jpg

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> get-item c:\temp\new11_22?1?.jpg


    Directory: C:\temp


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
-a----       10/19/2018   7:27 PM        2097152 new11_22[1].jpg
```

Comment: But prefix searches for the first part of a file name e.g. -Prefix abc will match abc.jpg abc.png etc. How can I get files with a name containing [ or ] ?